# Generate Trace of JUnit test on success

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have JUnit tests that work without errors. And what I would like to do is to generate a trace file of these tests for example havinge execution time of each test class, list of methods tested ant other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build tool should do this for you. For instance if you are using maven have a look at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/, for ant you could use https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html and https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do this with ant ?

Comment: added link to ant task.